# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n\log(1+nx)}{x^n}$ converges for all $x>1$ using "Weierstrass m-test"

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am preparing for my exam and need help with the following task:

Show that the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n\log(1+nx)}{x^n}$ converges for all $x>1$ using "Weierstrass m-test".

The problem is, that I can't find a $M_n$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq M_n$. If we could find one, we could then show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} M_n$ converges for all $x>1$ and according Weierstrass m-test, we could say that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n\log(1+nx)}{x^n}$ converges for all $x>1$.

Edit: Since $\frac{n\log(1+nx)}{x^n}\leq \frac{n^2}{x^{n-1}}$ we show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{x^{n-1}}$ converges $\forall$ $x>1$ We are using the ratio test. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ $\frac{(n+1)^2}{x^n}\cdot \frac{x^{n-1}}{n^2}$=$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ $\frac{(n+1)^2}{xn^2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^2x}+\frac{2n}{n^2x}+\frac{1}{n^2x}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{nx}+\frac{1}{n^2x}= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}$. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}<1$ for $x>1$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{x^{n-1}}$ converges for x>1. Is x=1, our series diverges obviously.

So according the Weierstrass m-test, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n\log(1+nx)}{x^n}$ converges for all $x>1$. Is this correct?

So, is there anyone who could give me a hint? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Suppose $x \ge q > 1$. Then, using $\log(1+w)\leq w$, $$
\frac{{n\log (1 + nx)}}{{x^n }} \le \frac{{n^2 }}{{x^{n - 1} }} \le \frac{{n^2 }}{{q^{n - 1} }}.
$$

Comment: @Gary Thank you for your answer. But why do we need q?

Comment: @Gary I edited the post. Is it correct?

Comment: Note that you are using the ratio test and not the root test. I am using $q$ because $M_n$ shoul dnot depend on $x$. The convergence is not uniform for $x>1$, but it is uniform for $x\geq q$ with any fixed $q>1$.